# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, spree

Hi I have included given code

```
 Spree::Order.includes(:ship_address).where('ship_address.country_id = ?', 52).references(:spree_address).count
```

and i am facing given error

```
 (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "spree_orders"."id") FROM "spree_orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_addresses" ON "spree_addresses"."id" = "spree_orders"."ship_address_id" WHERE (ship_address.country_id = 52)
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ship_address"
LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "spree_orders"."ship_address_id" WHERE (ship_addre...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "spree_orders"."id") FROM "spree_orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_addresses" ON "spree_addresses"."id" = "spree_orders"."ship_address_id" WHERE (ship_address.country_id = 52)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ship_address"
LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "spree_orders"."ship_address_id" WHERE (ship_addre...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "spree_orders"."id") FROM "spree_orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_addresses" ON "spree_addresses"."id" = "spree_orders"."ship_address_id" WHERE (ship_address.country_id = 52)
from /Users/TopFormInvestment/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@skinnymint/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.2/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:160:in `exec'
```

Checked in spree [model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb)

```
belongs_to :ship_address, foreign_key: :ship_address_id, class_name: 'Spree::Address'
    alias_attribute :shipping_address, :ship_address
```

Please guide me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following queries help.

```
Spree::Order.includes(:ship_address).where('spree_addresses.country_id = ?', 52).references(:spree_address).count
```